# Render custom json: how to render a date format correctly in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, date

I creating a custom json object with dates in it. Unfortunately when I want use the date in jQuery to turn into a Date object, the object turns to be invalid. This is the case for Date Strings like:

> 2011-12-14 00:59:59 +01:00

If I render it with the built in object.to_json the time gets rendered like this:

> 2011-12-14T00:59:59+01:00

This way I can turn this string in to a query date object.

So my question is how to render a date in rails so that it becomes the second format.

Thanks Markus

Answer (score 2):

As far i can see from the sources, the `to_json` method of `DateTime` is add by ActiveSupport ([source here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb)).

So you should monkey patch it in an initializer (such as `config/initializers/datetime.rb`) like this:

```
class DateTime
  def as_json(options = nil)
    strftime('%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
  end
end
```

Tested and working here: http://codepad.org/NRzqiJT3

Answer (score 0):

The following will work in all major browsers and ie7+ (I haven't tested ie6) if put in an initializer (e.g. config/initializers/)

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def as_json(options = {})
    strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to achieve similar goal:

```
class Date
  def as_json(options = {})
    I18n.localize self
  end
end
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Seems to be a neat solution. Thanks.